# quick way to access splistitem in different list?

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, spquery

I have 2 lists: listA and listB

listA has 2 fields:

- Title (text)
- PortalID (text)

listB has 3 fields:

- Title (text),
- listAField(lookup to listA Title field)
- UserID (text)

I have a UserID value and I need a quick way to get PortalID value.

Currently I'm using 2 SPQueries:

1. Gets listAField value
2. Gets PortalID value.

Is it possible to relate everything using one lookup directly?

Answer (score 0):

While creating the lookup column, you can use additional column settings to include the additional field PortalID. This will allow you to use one query only.